# Hit-n-Run Monte Carlo on convex polytope

Tags: linear-programming, monte-carlo

So, I'm currently trying to implement a MCMC to uniformly sampling hyper-points from the polytope defined as $\mathbb{K}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\;\;\text{s.t.}\;\; A\,x=b \}$ in the specific case where, given a generic linear transformation $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $b\equiv0\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and the boundary conditions $0\leq x\leq1$ hold.

Now, although I was able to succesfully perform the simulation (I am using Julia), there are some things I am not quite sure about:

- given the fact that polytopes of this this kind tend to have star-like shapes in higher dimensions, two pre-processing steps are required, before launching the simulation:

  1. the first regards the so-called *blocked-flux adjustment* which consists, quote from the text of the exercise, find fluxes $i$ such that $\max_{x\in K} x_i = \min_{x\in K} x_i = z_i$ and remove such variables from the system, adjusting the vector $b$. Can anyone please explain to me what the heck this means?
  2. the second consists in finding an optimal inner point in $\mathbb{K}$ as a starting point of the chain, which intuitevely enough has to be located far from the vertexes of the polytope. The text tells me this: *it can be done e.g. by computing* $\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x^{\min,i} +  x^{\max,i})$ *where* $x^{\min,i} \in \arg\min_{x\in K} x_i$ and $x^{\max,i} \in \arg\max_{x\in K} x_i$. Here I just do not understand the notation: I suppose I should compute a weighted average of the midpoints of each edge of the polytope but I can't see how this is related to the above formulation.
- as any coherent MCMC, the walk in the state space has to be s.t. it satisfies the **detailed balance**, which, for the present case, the text tells me that it should be the target distribution $$p(x) \propto \delta^m(Sx-b)\prod_i \theta(u_i-x_i)\theta(x_i-l_i) $$
  again, I have no idea how this is obtained nor how to compute them.

Comment: You seem to be struggling with an assignment that is poorly written or explained. I think that the only person who can really help you with that is the person who wrote or gave you the assignment.

Comment: Thanks @WolfgangBangerth; do you mean the text doesn't make sense the way it's written?

Comment: I don't have the whole assignment, nor do I know what you learned in class. For example, the notation you use may make sense to you, but we don't know what $\delta^m$ or $\theta$ stand for. The point I'm trying to make is that the only person who can help you is the instructor who gave you the assignment.